# Elixir - How to kill supervisor when linked process is killed?

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

In my Elixir application, I have two apps called `market_manager` and `candle_manager`.

In app `candle_manager`, I have this tree structure:
[image]
In app `market_manager`, I have this one:
[image]
`MarketManager.ManagersSupervisor` is a dynamic supervisor that can start managers. When I start one `Manager`, I get this:
[image]
Also, the manager that I started will start a new child in `CandleManager.Bitfinex.RealtimeSupervisor` called `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor`:
[image]
`CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` is started with `:temporary` restart, and its PID is linked to the `Manager` one via `Process.link`.

So, for example, if `Manager` has PID `<0.612.0>` and `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` PID `<0.613.0>` there will be a link between these two (I can confirm via `:observer`).

Now, if I go to `:observer` and kill `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor`, then `Manager` will receive the exit message and kill itself too (as expected).

But, if I kill the `Manager` instead, `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` is not killed and `Manager` will fail to restart since it will try to start a new `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` and fail with `:already_started` error.

So, my question is, does `Process.link` work correctly with `Supervisors`? How can I make `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` kill itself when `Manager` is killed?

Just for completeness, here is `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` code, it doesn't have anything fancy that I can see breaking the `Process.link` logic.

```
defmodule CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  alias CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime

  require Logger
  def start_link(args) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl Supervisor
  def init([market_manager_pid: _pid] = args) do
    childrens = [
      {Realtime.Websocket.Server, []},
      {Realtime.Manager.Server, []},
      {Realtime.TradeToCandle.Server, []},
      {Realtime.TradeDiscarder.Server, args}
    ]

    Supervisor.init(childrens, strategy: :one_for_all, max_restarts: 0)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But, if I kill the `Manager` instead, `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` is not killed [...]

You are trying to break OTP contracts and OTP obviously does its best to prevent you from shooting your own leg.

[`DynamicSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html) was *intentionally* created to survive children crashes.

> it will try to start a new `CandleManager.Bitfinex.Realtime.Supervisor` and fail with `:already_started` error

`:already_started` response is *by no mean an error*. It’s an indication that the process was already started before and you are all set.

> does `Process.link/1` work correctly with `Supervisor`s?

It sure does. But usually when building OTP supervision trees one does not call `Process.link/1` directly, it’s all done by proper [`child_specs passed through`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html?#module-how-to-supervise).

---

Unfortunately, that’s all I can tell so far since you did not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and refer to names not mentioned anywhere in screenshots nor in code.

Try to name your supervisors appropriately, draw the tree on the paper and implement it in the code by providing proper lists of `child_specs` for `children` in all respective calls to `Supervisor.init/1`. You are unlikely in a need to call `Process.link/1` manually, and I doubt you actually need the `DynamicSupervisor` there.